# how to send data from one view controller to another view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

hi i am new to ios programing and i am developing a calendar app in which i am using tabbarcontroller which have 5 viewcontroller. My probelm is that in 2nd viewcontroller i want to change the date wich is displaying in the first viewcontroller, how can i do this. pls help....

i had made a property in appdelegate class

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)NSString *date;
```

AND THEN made a object of appdelegate in both the view controller and then in 2nd view controller

```
AppDelegate *obj=[[AppDelegate alloc]init];
    obj.date=@"ABCDSE";
```

and in 1st view controller

```
 AppDelegate *obj=[[AppDelegate alloc]init];
    mylabel.text=obj.date;
```

Comment: you should access appdelegate like `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]`, while you creating new one.

Comment: i tried it but its not happning...

Comment: you don't need to use appdelegate to pass data between view controllers. use their properties

Answer (score 0):

You don't create an app delegate, you get a reference to it:

```
AppDelegate *ad = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

Then you access the string:

```
mylabel.text = ad.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**FirstViewController**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSString *strTemp = @"Pass string here";
  FirstViewController *firstView = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];

  firstView.Str = strTemp;

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:firstView  animated:YES];
}
```

**SecondViewController.h**

```
@interface SecondViewController: UIViewController
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *Str;
@end
```

And check out some video tuts

http://www.verious.com/tutorial/ios-5-passing-data-between-view-controllers/
http://www.verious.com/tutorial/iphone-development-tutorial-passing-data-to-another-view/